# "Original" coupling constant of the Higgs with the electron, taking into account renormalization

Tags: quantum-field-theory, standard-model, higgs

I read Peskin, Schroeder, "An introduction of quantum field theory". Formula (20.100) gives the electron mass after the Higgs mechanism as

$m_e=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\lambda_e v$

Here $v$ is related to the classical value of the Higgs field in vacuum, and can be assumed positive, I think. Normally, the coupling constant $\lambda_e$ is also taken positive, to bring a positive electron mass $m_e$. My question relates the sign of  $\lambda_e$, taking into account the renormalization of the mass of the electron.

Thus, as much as I know, renormalization will bring the electron an additional positively infinite mass. To compensate beforehand, I assume that, in the beginning, the electron bare mass will be chosen infinitely negative (such that the total mass is finite). Using Higgs mechanics, one can satisfy such a requirement choosing a negative $\lambda_e<0$.

Above logica is just my reasoning, I personally never went through renormalization using the Higgs, but I noticed that in QED renormalization the bare mass has the negative form $m=m_o-a/\epsilon$, where $a>0$ and the infinitezimal $\epsilon \rightarrow 0^+$ (see for example relation 9.113 in Ryder, "Quantum field theory").

I wonder if such a reasoning on the negative sign of  $\lambda_e$ is correct, when taking account the renormalization of the electron mass.

Thanks, cristian

Comment: By chiral symmetry, $\delta m_e \propto m_e$. From memory, with the cut-off at the Planck scale, the correction is $\sim1\%$. I think Ryder is renormalisation of a scalar field, which has no symmetry to protect its mass...

Comment: I see what you mean. I used Peskin fomula 7.29 to calculate $\delta m = 0.17 m_0$, when cut-off is Plank. So, you would say that "negative electron mass" is a false problem, I assume, since the electromagnetic contribution to the electron mass is about 10% in QED. Is is so? Also, I see that this relate to Weisskopf electron self-energy, (V.F. Weisskopf, Phys. Rev. 56, 72 (1939)) I assume then he was right ...

Comment: ...also note that the phase of a fermion mass term is unobservable as a chiral rotation of the field gets rid of it. (If the fermion is coupled to a chiral gauge current this phase ends up in the vacuum theta term for the gauge field after removing it from the mass term.)

Comment: I used the same formula of Peskin to find out that the bare (original) mass is always positive, even though it tends to zero when integrating to a very large cutoff. So again, the whole discution on the negative electron mass based on the formula's $m=m_0-a/\epsilon$ (dimensional regularization in the first order) is in fact not true? For clarity, the formula I refer to is: $\delta m \rightarrow \frac{3 \alpha}{4 \pi}m_0 \log \left(\frac{\Lambda^2}{m_0^2} \right)$